# Post query missing an elseif statement

Tags: custom-post-types

I have a custom post type query which currently successfully returns tbe posts requested in the order specified. I would like to add an 'elseif' statement if there are no posts but am having absolutely no luck with it.

Can somebody please help me with how I insert the else statement?

I appreciate any help you can provide.

```
<?php $posts = get_posts(array(
'post_type' => 'retail_units',
'orderby' => 'date',
'order' => 'ASC'
));
if( $posts ) { foreach( $posts as $post ) { setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

<li>
<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
    <?php the_title(); ?>
</a>
</li>

<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<?php } wp_reset_postdata(); } ?>
```

Comment: You should work on your formatting and indentation. I personally believe this is one of your biggest problems As your code stands, it makes it difficult to read. `if( $posts ) { foreach( $posts as $post ) { setup_postdata( $post ); ?>` can, for eaxample, be broken up into three lines.  Also, get yourself a proper code editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `else` in PHP goes at the end of the `if` statements closing bracket, look at the following:

```
if( 1 == 1 ) {
    echo 'true!';
}
else {
    echo 'false.';
}
```

So you code would look something like this:

```
<?php 
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'retail_units',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'ASC'
        ));

    if( ! empty( $posts ) ) { 
        foreach( $posts as $post ) { setup_postdata( $post ); 
?>

    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </li>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
<?php 
    }
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
    } else { 
?>
    <li>No Posts Found.</li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you Howdy_McGee, that worked perfectly. I hadn't considered having the else statement after the reset command.